# How to pass the current build number to a triggered job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that triggers another job as a post-build action. Let's call the jobs *job1* and *job2* accordingly. *job2* needs to know the build number of the job that triggered it which is *job1*. I found about [Parameterized Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) that seems to be able to accomplish that task but I can't get my head around how to do that. What I tried is to export the build number environmental variable `%BUILD_NUMBER%` from *job1* hoping that can somehow to access it in *job2*. So in *job1* I did:

[image]

and then, in *job2* I tried to access this value but it doesn't look like this approach works.

[image: access build number value from job2]

In this case, `%BUILD_NUMBER%` prints out the build of current job (*job2*) and `buildNum` does not resolve and just remains plain text.
What can I do to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

*Job1*

- Installing the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)
- Creating a trigger like this

  - Change ***target1*** to ***Job2***
  - Change **foo=bar** to **buildNum=%BUILD_NUMBER%**

[image]

*Job2*

- Installing the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)
- Config it like this

[image]

[image: access build number value from job2]

Comment: Thanks. Are you certain about *job2* configuration? I think this String parameter is supposed to be exported, not imported. Anyway it does not work.

Comment: I'm using this flow. What logs do you get when running it?